# Laravel "conditional routing"?

Tags: laravel

I have an interesting problem I need to solve and looking for best way to approach it.

Have a laravel 5.4 app that is fronted by a few public static pages. App is a golf performance tracking app. User enters data and the app does some analysis and shows graphs etc.

Problem is that if a new user signs up they have no data and they need to enter a score for the app to "work"

User signs up, verifies email, etc. so they now have authorized access to the app.

What I want to do is check if the user has any scores in the db (fine I can do that easily) then if they have at least one score entered send them to the app. Fine.

If they have no scores I want to send them to a view that explains that they need to have to enter a score and present the form to do so.

Question is:

where is the best place to check if the user has no scores and then send them to the view to enter the score and not allow them to access any of the app views.

Looking for the best way to do this? Is it create the condition and check the db in the routes/web.php? Is there a better way to accomplish it? and if so what do I do with the routes that sit in:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom middleware and check if the user has score and redirect to any route or display any view you want. Something like this.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    if ($user && ($user->score == 0)) {
        return redirect()->route('instruction');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Apply this new middleware to all the routes which shouldn't be accessed by users with no scores. Also make sure you use this middleware after auth and not before.

Comment: I added custom middleware and added it to Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth', 'CUSTOMMIDDLEWARE']], function () {

I used both return redirect()->route('scores.create'); return redirect()->action('PlayerScoresController@create');

Both produce, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Is there another place I should add the CUSTOMMIDDLEWARE?

Comment: @BrianMoffatt you're doing it right, just make sure you don't wrap the route you're redirecting to with the same middleware. In this case `scores.create`. This will lead to an infinite redirection since this route would also need the need to have a score more than zero.

Comment: Ok, so create a new route for scores.create I can;t use my existing view. Is that right

Comment: You can use your existing view or route. But when you use an existing route, you need to make sure it doesn't use the score check middleware. In both your examples you've commend you're redirecting to a route which might be wrapped with the same middleware.

Comment: What is the way to exclude a route from a middleware check if it's wrapped in the Route::group? 

for instance here is my web.php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth', 'NewPlayerMiddleware']], function () {

    Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'index','uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
    Route::resource('player/scores', 'PlayerScoresController');

I want to use the resource @create in the player/scores route. 

How do I exclude that from the NewPlayerMiddleware?

Comment: Don't add the new middleware to the resource using the route group. Instead enable it using the controller constructor. In this case add this to the `PlayerScoresController`, `public function __construct()
{
 $this->middleware('NewPlayerMiddleware')->except('create');
}` and for other controllers which need this, add `public function __construct()
{
 $this->middleware('NewPlayerMiddleware');
}`

Comment: I got it thanks!!!

I actually nested the route group in web.php. I will try it your way also